# Need to fix width of site to remove horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, width

I'm simply trying to remove the horizontal bar. I'm vewing the site on 1280x800 resolution so there shouldn't be a horizontal bar anyways.

It happens in chrome, firefox, and safari.

You can visit the site: http://ilmioforno.com

And my code is,

```
 body {
background: #f1eee3;
color: #111;
margin: 0;
   }
 #page {
   border: solid black 4px;
   clear: both;
}

 #wrap { 
   clear: both; 

    }

 #content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    background: #b63b3b;
    border: 3px solid #942a2a;
    color: #51301f;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 65%;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `div#nav` it has a `span-24` which sets the width to 950px, while you also have margin left of 360px. This effectively makes for a 1310px overall width since youre not hiding the overflow on any of the containing elements. You need to adjust the width of your nav. I assume youre overall hearder/page is 950 so that means your nav should be `950 - 360 = 590` at the most.

Answer (score 2):

well you can use CSS property overflow-x
for example:

```
#content
{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

it will remove horizontal scrollbar...

you can try it on this site
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp

Answer (score 1):

remove `maring-left` from `#nav`:

```
#nav {
   color: #51301F;
   /*maring-left: 360px;*/
   margin-top: -120px;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 22px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   background: none;
}
```

and add it to `.menu`:

```
.menu{
   maring-left: 360px;
}
```